# How disable click and hover of certain grid row's during databound event?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

In my databound event every globalGroupLevel that is a 0, the row is grey, but I have no idea on the correct way to disable those rows so they can't be clicked and remove the hover, here is my databound event

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    var data = this.dataSource.data();
    $.each(data,
        function (i, row) {
            if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") === 0) {
                var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
                element.addClass("colored-row");
                element.find(".k-hierarchy-cell a").remove();
            }
        });
}
```

Here are all the ways that I have tried to remove the click event and the hover effect, none of these worked

```
element.removeClass("k-state-selected");
$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
$(this).off('hover');
$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
element.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
$(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
element.canSelect(false);
element.removeClass("tr:hover");
$(this).removeClass("tr:hover");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the click event you can set all buttons with the `disabled` attribute. For `hover` you can create a new style for the element container, and when the container has the class 'disabled', the child elements will not have the hover.